# Node has one child, but I can't acces its name, content or grandchild

Tags: php, xml, parsing

I am very new to simpleXML and parsing in general, I am trying to parse a GPX file which is generated by tracking devises.
Here is the first node as an exemple, I have been able to retrieve lat, lon ele and time but I can't manage to access the different extensions.

[image: GPX file first node]

Here is the code I am using to access this part :

```
foreach ($fichier_gpx->trk->trkseg as $tracksegment){
    echo "Nouveau segment <br>";
    foreach($tracksegment->trkpt as $trackpoint){
        $point = new PointsGPX($trackpoint->time,$trackpoint->attributes()->lat,$trackpoint->attributes()->lon,$trackpoint->ele); //besoin de mettre attributes() pour récupérer lon et lat

        $tab_points->append($point);
        if(isset($trackpoint->extensions)){
            echo "I get here <br>";
            echo("There are ".$trackpoint->extensions->count()." children<br>");
            var_dump($trackpoint->extensions);
            $extensions_child = $trackpoint->extensions->children();
            echo $extensions_child->getName()." contains <br>";
            var_dump($extensions_child);
            echo("<br><br>");
        }
    }
}
```

And what it gives me :

[image: result loop]

However ! I can somehow get the values but not there node's name using this code :

```
foreach ($fichier_gpx->trk->trkseg as $tracksegment){
    foreach($tracksegment->trkpt as $trackpoint){
        $point = new PointsGPX($trackpoint->time,$trackpoint->attributes()->lat,$trackpoint->attributes()->lon,$trackpoint->ele); //besoin de mettre attributes() pour récupérer lon et lat

        $tab_points->append($point);
        if(isset($trackpoint->extensions)){
            echo "Point has extensions :<br>";
            echo "values : ".$trackpoint->extensions->asXML()."<br><br>";
            // foreach($trackpoint->extension->children() as $enfant){
            // }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Second way returns values]

Thank you infinitely for your help !

Comment: To get children in a namespace, you just need to tell which namespace you are interested: https://3v4l.org/nn99n

Comment: Please avoid using pictures in your questions. You haven't defined what kind of output you want, but the linked duplicates will show you how to get the namespaced node names and values. You are obviously going to need to loop through `$trackpoint->extensions` since there are more than one.

Comment: Many thanks to both of you, I didn't know about Namespace or XML structure, sorry if the post was a duplicate, but you just saved me a lot of time in research !

Answer (score 0):

You're displaying the XML on a web page, so the web browser is treating the XML tags as unknown HTML tags and ignoring them. Use `htmlentities()` to encode them so you'll see the tags.

```
echo "values : ".htmlentities($trackpoint->extensions->asXML())."<br><br>";
```

Comment: Thank you Barmar, it was not exactly what I wanted to do but knowing that html doesn't differenciate xml tags will be precious in this project !